# how to resolve JVM BUG in eclipce

Tags: java, eclipse, lucene, jvm

I have execute java project in eclipse.
In this I have used lucene searching algorithm and tried to note actual latency of my project,but I've deal with new one error

> "2015-12-11
>   12:32:50.199:INFO::org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectorManager$SelectSet@1cfa0fe 
> JVM BUG(s) - injecting delay1 times"

I have query about it:
1) why this bug occur?
2) how to resolve it?

Please if anyone have ans of this my query please answer it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Jetty page which talks about this error and potential workarounds:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/JVM_NIO_Bug

It also claims that:

> Java 7 should fix these bugs

Comment: yes you are right. I have had read it and I've used java 1.7 still it get errors.